# Error "node-pre-gyp install" on "npm install" of a VueJS project

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

When I run `npm install` inside a VueJS project cloned from Git I saw many errors. Analysing it I understand that the error is about the follow command: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`. So I tried execute just it and got the follow error:

```
augusto.cadini@CTNLDELL3G0FPZ2:~/Documents/particular/quinta-app$ node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.32
node-pre-gyp info using node@8.10.0 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp info build requesting source compile
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@12.14.1 | linux | x64
gyp info ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: quinta-app package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready:
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack package.json must declare these properties: 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack main
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_name
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_path
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.host
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:203:15)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:261:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at handle_gyp_opts (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/handle_gyp_opts.js:54:27)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at configure (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/configure.js:11:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/build.js:35:13
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:85:9)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1030-oem
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
```

This tell me that the error is on `package.json`, but the another develops the `npm install` works fine.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "quinta-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "firebase": "^7.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off",
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

**Complete npm install error**

```
augusto.cadini@CTNLDELL3G0FPZ2:~/Documents/particular/quinta-app$ npm install

> grpc@1.24.2 install /home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@12.14.1 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/your/cert.pem' 
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/your/cert.pem'
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
gyp ERR! stack     at readCAFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:437:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at download (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:409:22)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:162:19
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:30:20
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1030-oem
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1030-oem
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/augusto.cadini/Documents/particular/quinta-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/augusto.cadini/.npm/_logs/2020-01-15T14_41_45_831Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Note the line which says: `Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@12.14.1 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`

Do you know if this package is compatible with your node version? You may need to downgrade it or check it's version compatibility. Or update all of your existing packages and try again

Comment: same problem when try `npm install grpc`

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the follow steps:

1. Execute these steps: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally
2. `npm config set strict-ssl false`
3. Set your cert:  `npm config set cafile /path/to/cert/my_cert.pem --global`

In my case the path for cert is: `npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.pem --global`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had installed node version 12 instead of node version 10 and some of the packages (firebase) were expecting node 10.